# How to change Unit Price FREE caption in woocommerce wishlist

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I wanted to change the caption of Unit Price from **FREE** to **Not FREE** of wishlist in woocommerce. I made my research on the internet and found this code below:

```
<?php
add_filter( 'woocommerce_variable_free_price_html',  'hide_free_price_notice'); 
add_filter( 'woocommerce_free_price_html',           'hide_free_price_notice' ); 
add_filter( 'woocommerce_variation_free_price_html', 'hide_free_price_notice' ); 

function hide_free_price_notice( $price ) { 
   return 'Not FREE';
}
```

However, this code doesn't work.

I can modify this through jquery but not in PHP. I want to change this in PHP using add_filter but doesn't work.

FYI, I am using CherryFramework as my parent theme.

Does anybody know what is the problem here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After searching on the internet and viewed the templates/wishlist-view.php as suggested by @Visdish, I saw the *FREE!* word.. But, I don't want to directly modify the plugin. What I did is I created and saved the add_filter code below into my **functions.php**

```
function smz_change_free_to_tba(){
    return '[my_caption_here]';
}
add_filter( 'yith_free_text' , 'smz_change_free_to_tba');
```

Comment: I did not suggest you to modify core files of the plugin. I suggested to copy it to your themes folder and then modify it. This way you can modify it using template. So, can you upvote my answer?

Answer (score 1):

If the hook is not working for you, then you can customize templates/single-product/price.php

There, if you find price 0.00 then print "Not Free".

Comment: plugins/woocommerce/templates/single-product/price.php copy this file to your child theme and customize there. in your child theme, put under this folder structure: woocommerce/single-product/price.php

Comment: There is no 0.00 there. besides, I tried to remove the codes there but no effect on wishlist page..

Comment: This is for product details page. If you are using a plugin for wishlist, then it should have its own template files, which you can customize.

Comment: I am using a Yith plugin but it is not here.,

Comment: Okay. If you see there is templates/wishlist-view.php . You can customize that on line #168

Comment: thanks @Vidish. but I cannot modify the plugin. I added a filter into my functions.php as I posted on the answer above.

Comment: I did not suggest you to modify core files of the plugin. I suggested to copy it to your themes folder and then modify it. This way you can modify it using template. So, can you upvote my answer?